# слет админки revo modx на денвере

Tags: modx

Решаю проблему такую. Просто после ночного простоя на денвере пытаюсь войти в админку, но там пустой экран. Я набираю допустим следующий код

```
http://localhost/modx/modx/manager/?a=security/user,
```

то такое работает, а если вбивать в юрл

```
http://localhost/modx/modx/manager
```

Отключил компрессию css и js в настройках, тем не менее ситуация входа в главную админку не изменилась. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Замените Денвер на что-то современное.

Comment: Пустой экран наверняка свидетельствует о возникновении ошибки. Что в логах по этому поводу написано?